# How to group by 1 element and get sum of other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that goes like this:
[image: my db]
Now i'm trying to get all called columns and a sum of the duration for a specific `called` var.
Now i'm trying this :

```
select called,SUM(duration) as dursum,time,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch  
from Calls
where caller='somevalue'
group by called,time
order by called
```

Now the problem is that i guess because i order by `time` as well i don't really get distinct values by called, i get the same number several times, and ofcourse the sum acts the same, sums only part of the rows.

I can't remove the `group by time` as it will cause an error for using the `SUM` function.

Again i want the result to have every called number **once** per day and the dursum to contain all the duration sum **and** grouped by the batch column somehow...

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, not grouping by time brings you the correct resultset. However, the error occuring then is easily explainable: it is caused by the selection of  " time,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch " in the select clause -> thus you just need some kind of aggregation for the time-field (for instance MAX(time),CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MAX(time), 4) AS Batch.

Best regards

Comment: But i don't need one. i actually need the results to be grouped by that time, as for different day i do want the caller to show again.

Comment: Maybe I got your problem: you want group by day :-) -> this can be easily done: just wrap your query around an subquery which converts datetime to date!

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how i solved it in the end :

```
select called,SUM(duration) as dursum, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, time))as Batch2 ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch  
from Calls
where caller='0502081971'
group by called, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, time)),CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4)
order by called
```